# When two or more lines are captured, how to then prefix a '\t' character to every line in the capture group?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

This is something I have been coming across in VsCode Find/Find in files panels for some time and I each time I failed to find a way to do it.

```
;----- F20 -----
;F20
Hotkey, F20, MG_JWM_DownHotkey, Off
Hotkey, F20 up, MG_JWM_UpHotkey, Off
Return
;----- F21 -----
;F21
Hotkey, F21, MG_JWM_DownHotkey, Off
Hotkey, F21 up, MG_JWM_UpHotkey, Off
Return
;----- F22 -----
;f22
Hotkey, F22, MG_JWM_DownHotkey, Off
Hotkey, F22 up, MG_JWM_UpHotkey, Off
Return
```

Let's say the current file contents in Visual Studio Code consists of the above. And I want to prefix a `tab` to every line except the lines that start with `;---`, so that I can use those lines to fold the indented lines. The expected outcome should be:

```
;----- F20 -----
    ;F20
    Hotkey, F20, MG_JWM_DownHotkey, Off
    Hotkey, F20 up, MG_JWM_UpHotkey, Off
    Return
;----- F21 -----
    ;F21
    Hotkey, F21, MG_JWM_DownHotkey, Off
    Hotkey, F21 up, MG_JWM_UpHotkey, Off
    Return
;----- F22 -----
    ;f22
    Hotkey, F22, MG_JWM_DownHotkey, Off
    Hotkey, F22 up, MG_JWM_UpHotkey, Off
    Return
;----- F23 -----
    ;f23
    Hotkey, F23, MG_JWM_DownHotkey, Off
    Hotkey, F23 up, MG_JWM_UpHotkey, Off
    Return
```

This RegEx correctly captures only the lines that I want to prefix a `tab` character to:

```
;f2(.|\n)+?return
```

But when I try to prefix a `tab` to the captured group, only the first line in the captured gets gets a `tab` character prefixed to it. As shown [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/klkPRXA.png).

This simple small file was just an example, this is something I find myself wanting to much larger files but often give up because of not being able to act on every single line in a capture group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, neither https://regex101.com/r/8hDyuN/1 nor https://regex101.com/r/8hDyuN/2 work in that feature.

Comment: Search for `^(?!;---)` and replace with `\t` like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3gyk6/1)

Comment: Your regex matches 4 lines at a time not each line.  So putting a tab at the front should only put it in one place.  You need to match each line that you want to modify.  The negative lookahead from the answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(?!;---)^.+
```

and replace with

```
\t$0
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/0ZjWfP/latest

---

Explaination

- `(?!;---)` ensures all lines are captured but the ones that should not be indented
- `^.+` matches the whole line

And as you already did, then replace it with the match, preceeded with a tab.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you RegEx wizard :D

Comment: A simpler solution is to find `^(?!;---)` and replace with `\t`, this is because replacement works with zero width matches so just having an anchor is enough!

Comment: It also performs better because it doesn't involve capturing and replacing the rest of the line.

Comment: That is a very elegant solution!